# Lagging onClickListeners Android

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener, lag

I'm pretty new to android and am currently developing my third app, a button tapping game that involves a title activity, then a game activity. Before, When I wanted to re-run the game I would simply call onCreate() from inside the game activity but I'd much rather have it reset in a much smoother way, so I wrote a restart method to reset all the buttons back to their original state. The game runs fine when you run it from the title activity but when I try to restart the game, I find that some of my buttons are unresponsive when pressed. I've tried many things but can't seem to find what the problem is! I set the onClickListeners for all the buttons(there are 15 in total) in the onCreate() then don't touch them again besides changing their color and giving them animations, but I just can't seem to find what the problem is. Could it be a memory issue? they just seem to lag, like a have to hit them twice. I am also clearing the animations when the player looses the game.

I appreciate all the help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Some code examples of your onCreate method and the method where you do the resetting would be really useful.

Firstly, never call onCreate (or any of the other Activity/Fragment lifecycle methods) yourself. These are callbacks from the system to your Activity/Fragment to let you know that an action has been completed or a state in the lifecycle has been reached.

A few years ago I had a similar issue, where a button would just not respond to events anymore (onClick was never called for it). The reason was that the view got destroyed and a new one was created in its place, but the OnClickListener was still set on the old button. Now, from what you are saying here, this is not necessarily the case in your situation, but I can't tell exactly until you add the actual code to your question.